# Binarizing text and individual character coloring in java graphics 2d

Tags: java, text, colors, graphics2d

Hey guys I'm having trouble conceptually both coloring and binarizing text. 
So I'm using graphics 2d to draw to a bufferedimage(and displaying it using opengl). I can easily get every character colored by coloring while writing.

I can also easily do binarization of my image using Otsu's binarization method. The problem is that when I binarize I lose the location of connected components(as in I don't know whether the dot on an i belongs to that i), and thus have trouble coloring. If I keep my color I can't binarize. The problem is also compounded when I rotate and skew my characters(being displayed through open GL mapping).

I've also tried drawing and binarizing, then doing flood-fill 8 connectedness but some fonts are wonky and are broken(as in some characters are not truly connected).
My newest idea is to save a bufferedimage of every character and then try matching the binary image to the saved image, but that doesn't seem too great.

current process of generating 3d text image is graphics2d into buffered image->buffered image to texture -> texture to 3d object(mapping in openGL) -> read and save pixels -> save image

Any help or guidance would be great!

TLDR: I need a program to create text that is both binarized and skewed and isn't affected by font type. Thanks!